# Why I only getting id's back in response? IGDB api

Tags: api, rest, request, http-post, postman

I already read the documentation and I think I am making the simplest request in the correct way, but it always returns only the IDs, instead of all the fields of the games

Documentation example: [Documentation Example](https://api-docs.igdb.com/#examples)

The request header is fine. I know this because I can get the expected request if fields = * as querystring

**this is my request:**
[image]

Comment: I think it was a Postman problem. when using postman, when using another Postman version the same request gave me the response that I expected ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the fields you want inside the body.

Like this:

```
fields age_ratings,aggregated_rating,aggregated_rating_count,alternative_names,artworks,bundles,category,checksum,collection,cover,created_at,dlcs,expansions,external_games,first_release_date,follows,franchise,franchises,game_engines,game_modes,genres,hypes,involved_companies,keywords,multiplayer_modes,name,parent_game,platforms,player_perspectives,rating,rating_count,release_dates,screenshots,similar_games,slug,standalone_expansions,status,storyline,summary,tags,themes,total_rating,total_rating_count,updated_at,url,version_parent,version_title,videos,websites;"
```